# python: regular expression search pattern for binary files (half a byte)

Tags: python, regex, binaryfiles

I am using the following regular expression pattern for searching 0xDEAD4FAD in a binary file:

```
my_pattern = re.compile(b"\xDE\xAD\x4F\xAD")
```

but how do I generalize the search pattern for searching 0xDEAD4xxx? can't seem to cut through half a byte

Comment: You're going to have a headache the first time one of the bytes you're searching for is a regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regular expressions do allow searching over ranges.  Thus, to find a byte whose the first nibble is "4" use:

```
pattern = re.compile(b"[\x40-\x4F]")
```

The following test shows that it produces the desired output:

```
>>> for byte in ('\x3f', '\x40', '\x42', '\x4f', '\x50'): print bool(pattern.search(byte))
... 
False
True
True
True
False
```

To answer your specific question about searching for 0xDEAD4xxx, use:

```
my_pattern = re.compile(b"\xDE\xAD[\x40-\x4F].")
```

Comment: hey what if i want the search result to return me the last 3 hex characters as a separate group? how would I insert the () between that thingie you made?

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK, grouping only groups by bytes, not by nibbles.

Comment: Hey, it is not that bad.  Python offers bitwise operations.  Thus, you can take a byte and zero-out the upper or lower nibble and just work with what's left.

Comment: If you have some byte, say `byte=b'\x3c'`, then, as integers, the lower nibble is `ord(byte) & ord(b'\x0f')` and the upper nibble is `(ord(byte) & ord(b'\xf0')) / 16`

Comment: I used: 
my_pattern = re.compile(b"\xDE\xAD([\x40-\x4F][\x00-\xFF])")
to get two groups then:
my_integer = int(binascii.hexlify(sr.group(1)[-3:],16);

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll be best served by converting your binary string to an ASCII hexadecimal string, and applying your regex(s) to that.  I don't believe regex's are intended to work with binary data; you might be able to get it to work, but don't be amazed if there are surprises along the way.

Answer (score -2):

If i were in your situation, i'd try hexdump with grep.