# Only keep alpha numeric character and pre-defined specific character

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a mixed-encoding file and I just want to keep alpha numeric and some character like: .(dot), /(dash), |(Vertical bar), white-space (not include \t, \n, \f). The other characters should be replace by a white space. Result content would be out to another file.

Below is my code:

```
def clean(input):
    string_list = list(input)
    for idx in range(0, len(string_list)):
        if not re.match("\w|\s|\||\.|/", string_list[idx]):
            string_list[idx] = " "
    return "".join(string_list)
file_in = "input.txt"
file_out = "output.txt" 
with open(file_in, "r") as f1:
    with open(file_out, "w") as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line_raw = clean(line)
            f2.write(line_raw)
print "Finished!"
```

I noticed that my output file still contained some special characters like "form feed" or "new line" existed (they should be remove). 
Is there any chance that some invisible Unicode character still existed? 
I doubt I should read the file in binary mode and use regex with byte like this link: 
[python: regular expression search pattern for binary files (half a byte)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344679/python-regular-expression-search-pattern-for-binary-files-half-a-byte)
but I have not succeeded yet. How could I achieve my purpose?

edit1: The white space I mentioned above should be a "real white space" (generated when we use space bar, not \t, \n, \f, etc)

Comment: It's because form feed and the like are included in the definition of whitespace (the \s). Maybe you need to match explicitly for space and tab, instead.

Comment: Btw, you replace a whitespace by a whitespace...

Comment: give us an input file text example

Comment: @saikumarm: since the data is sensitive, I can't publish an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you cannot publish the data
try this

```
>>> import re
>>> test_text = 'grep -i 'blair' filename.log | more'
>>> print re.sub(r'[^|\w\.]', ' ', test_text)
'grep  i  blair  filename.log   more'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I need. (I keep "\" so I slightly modify your code: 

    re.sub(r'[^|\w\./]', ' ',  test_text)